# How to configure Contentpresenter in nested ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following code:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Button>
        <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
              <Image Source="{...}"/>
              <ContentPresenter .../>
            </DockPanel>               
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
      </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I need button inside template for binding possibility. The nested template defines the appearance.

**The question:** `<ListBoxItem Content="Start"/>` does not work with code above. I need something like root Contentpresenter that refers to Contentpresenter inside button template. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Button>
        <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
              <Image Source="{...}"/>
              <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=Content}"/>
            </DockPanel>               
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
      </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: This exact scenario is what `TemplateBinding` is for: `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />`.